# Visual Studio Break on Delay Loaded dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How do you set an exception or a break-point for when a delay loaded dll is loaded by a process? For example, with windbg, you can set an exception `sxe ld <binary name>`.

I tried setting break-points like `{,,<binary name>.dll} EntryFunctions` for each entry functions. None of the break-points were hit.